# Hibernate user model not saving user-roles and role

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Whenever I try to save a user to my MySql database, it is only saving data to the **users** table and not the **roles-user** and **role** table. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

**(*Each user has many roles and each role can belong to many users*)**

I have 3 tables in my database:

```
users:       (id,username)
roles_users: (user_id, role_id)
roles:       (id,role)
```

followed by two Hibernate entities:

**This is my user model:**

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String username;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Role> roles;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    if (roles == null) {
        roles = new HashSet();
    }
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

**This is my Role model:**

```
@Entity(name = "roles")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "roles_users",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"role_id", "user_id"})})
private Set<User> users;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    if (users == null) {
        users = new HashSet();
    }
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

**This is the code I use to save a user and its role(s):**

```
    User user = new User();
    Role role = new Role();
    Set<User> userSet = new HashSet();
    Set<Role> roleSet = new HashSet();

    user.setUsername("Peter");
    role.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
    userSet.add(user);
    roleSet.add(role);

    role.setUsers(userSet);
    user.setRoles(roleSet);

    userService.saveUser(user);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you observe this is because `Role` is the entity that manages the `@ManyToMany` relation between it and `User` but you're not updating the `Role` object in your code.  I'd probably argue that is backward and that a `User` should probably own the relationship.

If you think about it, you create `Role` objects separately and later assign them to various `User` objects, as your code illustrates.  So it would make sense that `User` owns that relationship.

```
// Transaction 1
Role role = new Role( "ADMIN" );
session.save( role );

// Transaction 2
User user = new User( "Naros" );
user.getRoles().add( roleService.getRoleByName( "ADMIN" ) );
session.save( user );
```

Comment: ... I should have seen that faster. I switched the relationship and now the user is saving the Role object. Thx!